# Azure Functions : HttpRequestMessage does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I built a c# Azure functions app triggerred by an Http Request. The purpose of this app is to use digital twin to change the desired status of my device. In order to do that, I have imported the following dependencies (within the project.son file):

```
  "Microsoft.Azure.Devices": "1.17.2",
  "Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client": "1.19.0",
  "Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared": "1.15.2",
  "Newtonsoft.Json": "12.0.1"
```

Here is my error, when I want to return a HttpResponseMessage

```
req.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a status on the query string or in the request body");
```

I get the following error :

```
[run.csx] 'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and the best extension method overload 'HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<string>(HttpRequestMessage, HttpStatusCode, string)' requires a receiver of type 'HttpRequestMessage'
```

I suspect dependencies to cause this error but I haven't found any solution on internet.

Do you have an idea how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Go to kudu(`https://<functionapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) and navigate to `D:\home\data\Functions\packages\nuget`, delete `system.net.http` package then restart the function app.

Explanation:

`HttpRequestMessage` locates at assembly `System.Net.Http.dll`. I found that Function host references the assembly from GAC(Global Assembly Cache). On Azure, file path is `D:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll`. The reference cannot be redirected to the one we install using nuget(packages you installed reference `System.Net.Http.dll` internally), or we'll get error.